# Visual Studio 2022 Publish project to Centos 8 with Apache

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to create a web project in Visual Studio 2022 but can not as application type web is missing.

I do have ASP.NET and web development feature installed but I do not get Web application as n option in project properties.

**Feature**
[image: VSFeature]

**Project Type I create**

[image: I create a project]

**Application Properties**

[image: Application Properties]

Update 2021-12-04
I apologize for my lack of knowledge about how VS works as I recently started using it.

Actually what i am looking for is to be able to build and publish a basic website on a Linux server with Apache.

When I try to do this in a old project I got from my colleague which is build with .NET Framework 4.5 after publishing the project in a folder I get all folders and .cshtml files which I can upload to my server how ever when I create a new project from scratch using ASP.NET Core Web App template and publish I do not get same results.

Screenshot of the published project:

[image: Screenshot of the published folder]

After comparing both projects when I check project properties on old .NET Framework project I see the type is web but the new project which is created with .NET Core is console and I can not change it to web that is why I was wondering if it had to do with this.

It is only the .NET Core template which produces "wrong files" for me even PHP Tools template creates correct project type and produces correct files which i can upload on a linux server.

Comment: A Web Application's template "Output type" (default) setting is indeed a Console Application. That's expected normal and expected. There's no "Web application" here.

Comment: ASP.NET from .NET Framework and ASP.NET Core are quite different. Templates are not necessarily the same not equivament. Your question is totally unrelated to the title.

Comment: Will in that case I update the title to exactly what I am looking for publish a project to Centos 8 with Apache.

What files do i need to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Install the correct framework**

   .NET / .NET Core is different from .NET framework, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server) is a link that explains the difference between both platforms. [Here](https://auth0.com/blog/navigating-dotnet-maze/) is another link if you need more information about the two terms. Since you're using Apache + Linux, you should be building a dotnet web application or a dotnet core web application. From your screenshot, the project that was created is a .NET Framework Application.
   You can use bash or the command line to install it. Follow the instructions [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet). Then run `dotnet --version` to check the version to see that it installed correctly.
2. **Host it properly**

   Depending on the platform you will use to host the app, you need to set up the environment properly. For Apache Linux, here is a [full tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on how to publish and host your app. You will need a domain name too for this
3. **Razor Pages are compiled**

   Razor Pages are compiled by default. You can read more about Razor Compilation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks your answer was very helpful.
I thought as .NET Core is cross platform it would be easy to create a website targeting Linux.

It looks like I must use .NET Framework as I want to have single file approach for Razor Pages.

I just did a quick test with a .NET Framework Web Application Empty template and published to folder and the result was as I wanted.

Comment: Oh nice. Then you must be running on IIS or something similar?

Comment: Actually I publish on a Folder then move it to a linux server.
What I see is correct that I get raw .cshtml files as output not .dll and .exe files.

I get RAW .cshtml files without changing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think windows application is the web creation that you are talking about in the third photo explaining about your application properties

Comment: I don't think so I just changed it and published my app in a folder getting some dll .exe files in the folder not ready .cshtml files as I get in a old Project created in VS 2012 and .NET Framework.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).